# Django - Create a form for adding multiple records

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a Form for adding multiple records with same form.

I've one model with UserStatus and one for Users.

**My models:**

```
class UserStatus(models.Model):
    TYPES = (
        ('enabled', 'Enabled'),
        ('deactivated', 'Deactivated'),
    )

    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zones, verbose_name="Zone")
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, verbose_name="User")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Status",
                            choices=TYPES ,
                            default='deactivated')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s - %s" % (self.zone, self.user, self.status)

class Users(models.Model):
        username = models.Charfield(max_length=60, verbose_name="Name")
        password = models.Charfield(max_length=250, verbose_name="Password")
```

**The Problem:**

I need to display a form with all my users and a selector after every user to choose his status:

```
form
|_ user - select name=status
|_ user - select name=status
|_ user - select name=status
|_ ..
```

How can I do this?
Can I do this with Formsets? (How?)

Comment: It sounds like formsets are what you're looking for. There's a great example/tutorial on formsets here: http://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html

Comment: Yes but I need to display an input for every user